# How to change username on RDS instance

Tags: postgresql, rds

I have a single RDS postgresql instance with username 'psql' owning the database. How do you change the username?

Comment: Why bother? What are you trying to solve?

Comment: Because in a lot of provisioning code spinning up instances, it would be easier for me to change the username on a single RDS instances; hence why I asked the question.